# How to concatenate a property expression and a lambda using Select?

Tags: c#, reflection

I would like to create the following expression dynamically:

```
e.Collection.Select(inner => inner.Property)
```

I created this code to do it, however I have an issue when I execute the expression call, someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

```
private static Expression InnerSelect<TInnerModel>(IQueryable source, ParameterExpression externalParameter, string complexProperty)
{
    // Creates the expression to the external property. // this generates: "e.Collection".
    var externalPropertyExpression = Expression.Property(externalParameter, complexProperty);

    // Creates the expression to the internal property. // this generates: "inner => inner.Property"
    var innerParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TInnerModel), "inner");
    var innerPropertyExpression = Expression.Property(innerParameter, "Property");
    var innerLambda = Expression.Lambda(innerPropertyExpression, innerParameter);

    return Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Select", new [] { typeof(TInnerModel) }, externalPropertyExpression, innerLambda);
}
```

Error:

> No generic method 'Select' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is
>   compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type
>   arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

Comment: `"I have an issue"` -- It would _really_ help to know what your issue is

Comment: @maccettura ops, I changed the question adding the error.. sorry

Comment: The error text tells you that there is no such method called *Select* on that collection type *Queryable*

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi, no that is not what the error says :)

Comment: @RenatoLeite, what is the first argument parameter of this extension method (look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2)? The first argument parameter for `Queryable.Select` seems to be missing in your code...

Comment: My advice to you is that you write a small program in which you construct a lambda `e => e.Collection.Select(inner => inner.Property)` that is converted to the appropriate expression tree type, and then examine the code which the C# compiler generates for you to build the inner lambda. Compare what the C# compiler generates to what you generated by hand; likely you will find that you're missing a necessary quotation operation.

Comment: But that aside, elgonzo is correct. `Select` takes two type parameters. You are passing one.  You need to pass two.

Comment: I note that your method takes a parameter `source` which it does not use in the body. What is the purpose of this parameter?

Comment: Thank you guys, I will test it..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, first off, the primary problem is very simple. As the error message says, you haven't passed enough type arguments to Select.  But when you fix that, you'll still have a problem, and that problem will be much harder for you to see and understand.

Let's dig into that.

You wish to represent this as an expression tree:

```
e.Collection.Select(inner => inner.Property)
```

Let's begin by rewriting it in its non-extension-method form.

```
Queryable.Select<A, B>(e.Collection, inner => inner.Property)
```

Where `A` is the collection member type and `B` is the type of `Property`.

Now, suppose you had this expression in your program.  **What would it actually do at runtime?**  It would construct an expression tree for the lambda and pass it to Queryable.Select.  That is, it would do something like:

```
var innerParameter = parameterFactory(whatever);
var lambdaBody = bodyFactory(whatever);
var lambda = makeALambda(lambdaBody, innerParameter);
Queryable.Select<TInnerModel>(e.Collection, lambda);
```

Right?  You with me so far?

Now, suppose we wish to translate *this* program fragment to an expression tree that could itself be the body of a lambda. That would be:

```
var theMethodInfoForSelect = whatever;
var receiverE = valueFactory(whatever);
var thePropertyInfoForCollection = whatever;
var theFirstArgument = propertyFactory(receiverE, thePropertyInfoForCollection);
...
```

Again, with me so far?  Now, the crucial question: **what is the second argument**?  It is NOT the value of `lambda`, which is what you are passing. Remember, what we are doing here is constructing an expression tree which **represents the code that the compiler is generating for that thing**, and the expression tree that is in lambda is **not** that.  You're mixing levels!

Let me put it this way:  the compiler is expecting "**add one and three**".  You are passing **4**.  Those are very different things!  One of them is a *description of how to obtain a number* and the other one is a *number*. You are passing an expression tree. What the compiler is expecting is *a description of how to obtain an expression tree*.

So: do you have to now write code that generates expression trees for all of `lambda`'s construction code?  Thank goodness no.  We provided you a handy way to turn *an expression tree* into *a description of how to produce an expression tree*, which is the `Quote` operation.  You need to use it.

So, what is the right sequence of events that you need to do to build your expression tree? Let's walk through it:

First, you'll need a `ParameterExpression` of the type of `e`, which you already have in hand.  Let's suppose that is:

```
ParameterExpression eParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(E), "e");
```

Next, you will need a method info for the `Select` method.  Let's suppose you can correctly get that.

```
    MethodInfo selectMethod = whatever;
```

That method takes two arguments, so let's make an array of argument expressions:

```
    Expression[] arguments = new Expression[2];
```

You'll need a property info for your `Collection` property.  I assume you can get that:

```
    MethodInfo collectionGetter = whatever;
```

Now we can build the property expression:

```
    arguments[0] = Expression.Property(eParam, collectionGetter);
```

Super.  Next we need to start building that lambda.  We need a parameter info for `inner`:

```
    ParameterExpression innerParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Whatever), "inner");
```

We'll need a property info for `Property`, which I assume you can get:

```
    MethodInfo propertyGetter = whatever;
```

Now we can build the body of the lambda:

```
    MemberExpression body = Expression.Property(innerParam, propertyGetter);
```

The lambda takes an array of parameters:

```
    ParameterExpression[] innerParams = { innerParam };
```

Build the lambda from the body and the parameters:

```
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<X, int>>(body, innerParams);
```

Now the step you missed. **The second argument is the quoted lambda, not the lambda**:

```
    arguments[1] = Expression.Quote(lambda);
```

Now we can build the call to Select:

```
    MethodCallExpression callSelect = Expression.Call(null, selectMethod, arguments);
```

And we're done.

---

Give someone an expression tree and you give them an expression tree for a day; teach them how to find expression trees themselves and they can do it for a lifetime.  How did I do that so fast?

Since I wrote the expression tree code generator, I had some immediate familiarity with the problem that you were likely to have. But that was ten years ago, and I did not do the above entirely from memory. What I did was I wrote this program:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
public interface IQ<T> {}
public class E
{
    public IQ<X> C { get; set; }
}
public class X
{
    public int P { get; set; }
}
public class Program
{
    public static IQ<R> S<T, R>(IQ<T> q, Expression<Func<T, R>> f) { return null; }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<E, IQ<int>>> f  = e => S<X, int>(e.C, c => c.P);
    }
}
```

Now I wished to know what code was generated by the compiler for the body of the outer lambda, so I went to https://sharplab.io/, pasted in the code, and then clicked on Results --> Decompile C#, which will compile the code to IL and then decompile it back to human-readable C#.

This is the best way I know of to quickly understand what the C# compiler is doing when it builds an expression tree, regardless of whether you know the compiler source code backwards and forwards. It's a very handy tool.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the answer, I will test the code with with your recommendations.